# How to include a TabLayout in a Toolbar in Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i was trying to implement a tabbed view using `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` in a `fragment`,
i managed to do that but the tabs are not included in the toolbar which is located at the top of the screen.
i have included the screenshot of what i have got.
[image]
can someone please tell me how i can move the tabs to the toolbar and also the tabs doesnt change
when they are touched they only change when swipped left or right.

i have tried adding the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` in `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` in the tabslayout.xml file
it add a blue background on it and the touches work but still its not included in the toolbar.

Here are the codes.

**1.Tabs.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Tabs extends Fragment {

    public Tabs() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mekeleLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_layout,container,false);



        viewPager = (ViewPager) mekeleLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) mekeleLayout.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return mekeleLayout;
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "RESTAURANTS");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "CAFES");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "HOTELS");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

**2.tabslayout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**3.activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**4.app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.surafel.information.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a theme for the activity which does not have an Action Bar.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to android can you describe your answer a little in detail.thanks

Comment: In the activity tag of main activity of the manifest add this code   "<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" ...>"

Comment: Am not using activity am using fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:theme="@style/appBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:tabBackground="@color/app_bar_color"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/viewPagerTheme"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

add appbar theme in your styles.xml

```
   <style name="appBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

Comment: This solves the touch problem it also adds a background same as the toolbar but it is not still included.

Comment: check out my edited post in that i have edited appBar theme just add in styles.xml

Comment: It's not working the way I want...can you start a chat room please let me send you another screenshot of what I got now

Comment: Ohk you make it after 1 hour i will be online and problem in your java code